# Show record number(as serial number) in crystal report detail section

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report in which i am showing records in detail section **Down then Across** direction, here divided detail section in two vertical parts, i need to show **line number only on left part**(resets on each page). For this I used running total, it works but shows on both the sides.

Is there any way to show line number only on left part??

Please help

Comment: Provide us a photo of your problem.

Comment: Please find attached link http://screencast.com/t/0Pw9nf06Kw

Answer (score 1):

It's built-in functionality in crystal report.

Just insert special field "Record Number" and it will display Serial Number in detail section.

***Right click on design area -> Insert -> Special Field -> Record Number***

Answer (score 0):

try this, create a formula

```
WhilePrintingRecords;  
numbervar srno;  
srno := srno + 1;
```